# Call function within a function PHP

Tags: php

```
1    function foo($i){
2       return bar($i)*4;
3       function bar($i){
4           return $i*4;
5           }
6       }
7    echo foo(4);
```

return

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function bar() in /var/www/index.php on line 2
```

why doesn't it work? it works well in javascript, while it works when i do this:

```
function foo($i){
   return bar($i)*4;
   }

function bar($i){
   return $i*4;
   }
```

Comment: The first doesn't work in JS either. And second works in JS too. (But note that the first, in PHP, doesn't create a locally-scoped closure but simply a global function IIRC).

Comment: Why do you expect a thing working in one language to work in another one?

Comment: @delnan: It does work in JavaScript,  because of hoisting. Function and variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the function.

Comment: that wouldn't work in any languages... code after return....

Comment: @Felix: Ah, yes. I keep forgetting this ugly inconsistency between `var f = function () {}` and `function f() {}` (wishful thinking?).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Define the function above your return value, otherwise it never gets executed.

```
<?php
function foo($i){
    function bar($i){
        return $i*4;
    }
    return bar($i)*4;
}
echo foo(4);
?>
```

Comment: Yes order of events, saw that immediately

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work as you are calling bar() before it has been created.
See example 2 here:- http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 1):

Your code never reach `function bar(...)`, therefore it's never defined.

You need to put your `bar()` function before your `foo()` or before the `return bar`. (Answer based on your first example).

With your second example you probably define `bar()` before you use `foo()` therefore `bar()` is defined and it works fine.

So as long as you have your function defined when you hit a certain spot in your code it works fine, no matter if it's called from within another function.

Answer (score 1):

If you define function within another function, it can be accessed directly, but after calling parent function.
For example:

```
function a () {
    function b() {
    echo "I am b.";
   }
echo "I am a.<br/>";
}
//b(); Fatal error: Call to undefined function b() in E:\..\func.php on line 8
a(); // Print I am a.
b(); // Print I am b.
```

Answer (score 0):

Execution not execute after return statement

change your code like this

```
 function foo($i){
 function bar($i){
  return $i*4;
 }
 return bar($i)*4;     
}
echo foo(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having a "recent" answer, here's what I did:

```
function printRx($conn, $patient)
{
    function rows($rows, $tod)
    {
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($tod); $x++) {
            if ($tod[$x] == 1) {
                $rows++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    $tod['prn'] = (explode('|', $row['prn'])) ?? null;
    $rows = rows($rows, $tod['prn']);
    return;
}
```

Works beautifully